# Disable email field on WooCommerce customer account details

Tags: customization, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

Is there a possibility to disable the email field on WooCommerce customer account details? Or Is there a hook or action available to do such thing? I'm just using a pre-made themes and not that much into PHP. Have tried this plugin called "Prevent Email Change" by Happy Plugins, but it didn't worked.

Would really appreciate any help from this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by adding this code to `functions.php`:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);    
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields', 1000, 1 );
```

But it is wrong approach, since WooCommerce uses email to notify user about status of the order.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Yup I knew that. But what I wanted is that they can register their email upon checkout and then once their account has been completely created, they cannot change their email anymore on the Account Details page. Would that be possible?

Comment: WordPress does not have filter or hook to prevent changing of email. Happy Plugin just disables email field on admin page, so it cannot prevent actions on Account Details page in WooCommerce. But what is reason to prohibit? Users are identified by ids.

Comment: I have a valid reason for this. I am creating an eLearn site that has restricted access. Only users from whitelisted domains can join. The email validation is done upon registration, but users can still change their email via this page, which shoudn't happen.

Comment: this just deletes the field from display.  Does not disable it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use. I was also troubleshooting with wrong emails on registered accounts. So I simply disabled the field and set it to `'required'   => false` if the user is logged in.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email'] = [
        'label' => 'E-Mail-Adresse',
        'required'  => false,
        'custom_attributes' => [
            'disabled' => 'disabled',
        ]
    ];
} else {
    $fields['billing']['billing_email'] = [
        'label' => 'E-Mail-Adresse',
        'required'  => true,

    ];
}
```

Hope this helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

I found in this file:
**wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\class-wc-countries.php**:

public function **get_address_fields**( $country = '', $type = 'billing_' )

Set required to false and the email would be optional.

Comment: Hi Manuel, welcome to wordpress.stackexchange. While your answer is technically correct i have to downvote it because editing a plugin like that isn't recommended. What would happen if the plugin we updated and the edits deleted? It's better to use a hook or filter function to accomplish OP's goal. Thanks for joining in, hopefully this is the first of many helpful answer you will provide :)

Comment: I up-voted it, because it is creative way to solve a problem.  Not necessarily the right way, but you found it and it may be the only solution for some. Not fair or right to discourage the solution, as one could have used a child theme  or any other number of overrides that are protected from plugin updates.  The better way is to change the [required] field to 0.  using the  add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );  values: [billing_email] => Array
                (
                    [label] => Email address
                    [required] => 1